# Bokeh slider change length of x

Tags: callback, slider, bokeh

In a given DataSeries I want to use a Bokeh slider to change the number of observations I show (the tail). Can this be done, if it can why won't my script work?

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider, Column
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

        ds = pd.Series( [i for i in range(20)],  pd.date_range('2016-01-02', periods=20, freq='D'))

        tail = 5
        ds.tail(tail)

    #Bokeh slider to change value of "tail"

    s1 = Slider(start=1, end=20, value=3, step=1)

    s1.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s1=s1, tail=tail), code="""
        ds.tail("tail", s1.get('value'));
    """)

    show(Column(s1))
    ds.tail(tail)
```

Comment: `CustomJS` callbacks are for running *JavaScript* code and only *in the browser*. Your browser does not know anything about Python in general, and in particular Pandas does not exist inside your browser. It will never be possible to use `CustomJS` callbacks to run real Python code (e.g. Pandas).  If you need to execute *real python code* in callbacks, that is what the Bokeh server exists for: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: Thanks. I did not get that.